# Pipe cannot read Enter key (C , Linux)

Tags: c, linux

I a beginner and I am writing a bi-direction communication programme in C, Linux for assignment submission. However, I've test and found that "enter" key is not readable via pipe as it contains 0 byte. If I accidentally press enter before normal characters are typed, the 2 screens turn to deadlock and cannot communicate. I tried getchar() or check the byte=0, but I don't know which position I should put the command to make it works. Any Ideas? Thanks

(Below is sender, I want the programme can send and receive msg)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

int main()
{ char  pipename1[] = "/tmp/pipe1"; /* pathname of the named pipe */
char    buf1[80];

char  pipename2[] = "/tmp/pipe2"; /* pathname of the named pipe */
char    buf2[80];

int i, n1,n2, fd1, fd2;

mkfifo(pipename1,0666);
printf("Please run receiver in other putty. \n");

fd1 = open(pipename1,O_WRONLY);
fd2 = open(pipename2,O_RDONLY);

while(1){ 

printf("Please enter a message. <To check message, press Enter>\n");


n1 = read(STDIN_FILENO,buf1,80); /* read a line */
   if (n1 <= 0) break; 
   buf1[--n1] = 0;
   write(fd1,buf1,n1); /* send the string */



while ((n2 = read(fd2,buf2,80)) > 0) { /* read from pipe */ 
buf2[n2] = 0;
printf("\n <player2> [%s] \n",buf2,n2);
break;}


}

close(fd1);
close(fd2);
unlink(pipename1);
unlink(pipename2);
exit(0); }
```

(Edited) Actually I created another end to read msg, code is below

```
int main()
{  char pipename1[] = "/tmp/pipe1"; /* pathname of the named pipe */
char    buf1[80];

char  pipename2[] = "/tmp/pipe2"; /* pathname of the named pipe */
char    buf2[80];
int i, n1,n2, fd1, fd2;

mkfifo(pipename2,0666); /* make file with the file name defined in pipename1, 0666 is permission every one can read & write */
printf("Please run receiver programme in another browser\n");

fd1 = open(pipename1,O_RDWR);
fd2 = open(pipename2,O_RDWR);

while(1){ 
printf("<Please enter a message.\n");

n2 = read(STDIN_FILENO,buf2,80); /* read a line */
if (n2 <= 0) break; 
buf2[--n2] = 0;
write(fd2,buf2,n2); /* send the string */


while ((n1 = read(fd1,buf1,80)) > 0) { /* read from pipe */
buf1[n1] = 0;
printf("\n <player1>[%s]\n",buf1,n1);
break;}
}       
close(fd1);
close(fd2);
exit(0);
}
```

Comment: No, the enter key **does not** contain a 0 byte - it will be encoded as either 10 or 13 depending on settings.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you write to the pipe (using `fd1`) but you don't *read* from it. Instead you open a totally unrelated filed and attempt to read from it.

A named pipe in the file-system is the single file initialized by `mkfifo`, and as all other pipes it has a write-end and a read-end, and both ends are accessed by opening the same file.

Comment: No, your edit maintains the original problem Joachim pointed out.

Comment: Then should I change "O_WRONLY" to "O_RDWR"
or "mkfifo" is not a good way to do bi-direction communication programme?

Any solution if I want to achieve bi-direction communication purpose?

Comment: @Angel - pipes are unidirectional, one writer, one reader. If you need bi-directional communication, you will need to create 2 pipes.

Comment: I' ve create 2 pipes, one is created in sender side, one is created in receiver side.
Actually, if I enter some words before pressing enter at both "sender" and receiver, it works, however, if I just press "enter" at both sides, the programme failed to send and receive.

Comment: @Angel You should just create *one* pipe, because each single pipe has both the write and the read end. If you create two pipes, you need an intermediate proxy-program that reads from one and writes to the other, probably not what you want. And if you just want to communicate privately inside your own process then use the [`pipe`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/pipe.2.html) system call instead of named pipes.